BQ25303J Typical Application circuit from datasheet
I am designing a new device and I want to include the BQ25303J in it.
My device will have a 3.7V 1-cell Li-Po battery, and will be charged from a USB. So, the BQ25303J comes handy for the battery charging purpose.
The thing is, I want the following behaviour:

If no USB is attached, the system is powered by the battery

If USB is attached, the USB must charge the battery AND power the circuit. The battery must only be charged in this case.


So, looking at the datasheet for the BQ25303J (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25303j.pdf?ts=1727334519693&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ25303J) I found on page 26, section 10.2.2 Typical Application with External Power Path. It looks just like what I want.

The problem is, when looking at this design, I am wondering, how does this work? Is the PFET Q4 properly connected?
Let's check Vgs for each case and see if the MOSFET is ON or not
I assume the voltage at PMID (VSYS) is 5V when USB is connected and is floating when USB is not connected.
I also assume a 0.7V voltage drop on the diode attached on the gate of Q4.
USB Connected
Vgs = Vg - Vs = (5V - 0.7) - (VPMID) = 4.3V - 5V = -0.7 V
MOSFET NOT ON
The voltage provided to the circuit is the voltage from the USB.
USB NOT Connected
Vgs = Vg - Vs = 0V - (floating) = ???
Then, here maybe the VSYS sees the voltage on the battery because of the diode on Q4.
In that case, assuming the battery has its nominal voltage 3.7V:
Vgs = Vg - Vs = 0V - 3.7 = -3.7V --> THE MOSFET IS ON
But here now, what I don't understand is, the current on a PMOS flows from source to drain, right? In this case, this would mean from VSYS to Battery, but this is exactly the opposite of what we want.
If anyone could clarify this to me, I would be so grateful.
Cheers to all.

Most discrete MOSFETs are kinda-but-not-exactly symmetrical so in power path hard switching applications like this and the fairly common reverse polarity protector you can swap the functions of source and drain. The characteristics will probably deviate some from the datasheet but the important part is the body diode is flipped around.

Hi @vir, thank you for your answer! :)
Why is it that the important part is the body diode is flipped around?
Also, could this circuit work if the PMOS (Q4) source and drain were flipped around? I mean, the source connected to the battery and the drain connected to VSYS

I believe also that the P-type MOSFET Q4 is connected backwards.  The apparent purpose of this transistor is to connect battery power directly to VSYS when VBUS is absent.  This configuration allows flow in that direction through the FET body diode without enabling the transistor, BUT...
If VBUS is present, it will flow through the Q1 diode (until Q1 is turned on) raising VSYS to 4.3V (5V once Q1 is on).  Since the battery is only 4.2V max while charging, it will not push the current through the diode.  It may be configured that way intentionally so that there's not a complete dropout while switching from USB to battery.  Once Q4 is on, the diode drop goes away.
At that point there's only the issue of a 4.3V gate against a 5V supply, so Q4 should have a minimum gate threshold of about 0.8 to 2V.
